# X and Y are independent random variables and their distributions are..

Tags: probability, random-variables, problem-solving

X and Y are independent random variables and their distributions are..

$P(X=1) = 0.1 $
$P(X=2) = 0.2$
$P(X=3) = 0.3 $
$P(X=4) = 0.4 $

$P(Y=4) = 0.4 $
$P(Y=2) = 0.3$
$P(Y=3) = 0.2 $
$P(Y=4) = 0.1$

I want to find the covariance. I know the $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) − E(X)E(Y)$, but how do I solve for $E(XY)$? Thanks.

Comment: By independence E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) and hence...

Comment: So it would be 0?

Comment: Also, if it asks to find the the covariance between X and Y does that mean find the covariance(X,Y)?

Comment: @JonDoe yes. That's right

Answer (score 0):

$X, Y$  are independent $\implies E[XY] \equiv E[X] \cdot E[Y] \iff E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] \equiv 0 \implies \boxed{\rm{Cov}(X,Y) \equiv0 \ }$

Answer (score 0):

You may verify the result by calculating it numerically:

$E(XY)=\sum_{i,j=1,2,3,4} X_iY_j P(X_i)P(X_j)$

So you sum up all 16 combinations of $X\cdot Y$ weighted by their probability product.

By this I came to $E(XY)=6$.

As $E(X)=3, E(Y)=2$, we have indeed:

$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=6-3\cdot 2=0$